# Read data from SQL Server database with c#

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have list of `BuilderString` which I want to contain data

```
 public  List<int> IDS = new List<int>();

 public List<StringBuilder> Items = new List<StringBuilder>();
```

What's wrong with this code?

```
SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=aya-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ItemSet;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataReader rdr2;
SqlCommand cmd2;

con2.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < IDS.Count; i++)
{
    cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select item From TransactiontData where idT=@IDS[i]", con2);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@IDS[i]"

    while (rdr2.Read())
    {
        Items[i].Append((StringBuilder)rdr2["item"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your code a bit:

```
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=aya-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ItemSet;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select item From TransactiontData where idT = @IDS", con2))
{
   // add the paramter to the command
   cmd2.Parameter.Add("@IDS", SqlDbType.Int);

   con2.Open();

   for (int i = 0; i < IDS.Count; i++)
   {
       // set the parameter value
       cmd2.Parameter["@IDS"].Value = IDS[i];

       // only *THEN* call ExecuteReader()
       using (SqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
       {
              while (rdr2.Read())
              {
                  // **NOT SURE** what you're trying to do here.....
                  // First of all, you need to just call Items.Add()
                  // to add new items to the list - and I'm TOTALLY
                  // UNCLEAR what you're trying to do casting the reader
                  // value to a StringBuilder.......
                  // 
                  // Items[i].Append((StringBuilder)rdr2["item"]);
                  //
                  // replaced with what *might* make more sense.....
                  Items.Add(rdr2["item"].ToString());
              }

              rdr.Close();
       }
    }        

    con2.Close(); 
}
```

Points to note:

- I would recommend to **always** put your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into `using() {...}` blocks to ensure proper disposal
- you need to add your parameter **and set its value** *BEFORE* you call `.ExecuteReader()`!
- Since the query itself never changes - there's no point in creating a new `SqlCommand` on every iteration. Create the command **once** - and then just set the parameter **value** (which is the only thing changing) once per iteration

Comment: there is error with range of list  " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. "

Comment: A combination/merge of this answer and the other from @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP would be best / work. For this answer: 1) setting `cmd2.Parameter["@IDS"].Value` needs to be `IDS[i]`, 2) most likely don't need a while around the `rdr2.Read()`, 3) the `Items` collection doesn't have any elements yet so you need to use `Items.Add()` rather than reference via `Items[i]`, 4) I don't think you can (or should) cast directly to a StringBuilder as the incoming value is actually just a string, and 5) should probably have `con2.Close()` after the `for` loop.

Comment: @srutzky: **(1)**: no, check my answer - the parameter name in my answer **IS** just `@IDS` - no point in having an indexing on that parameter name.... and **(5)** - not necessary, since the `using() {...}` blocks is **ensuring** proper disposal (and thus closing) of the connectoin

Comment: Marc, you misunderstood what I meant regarding #1. I was not referring to the param name. I am referring to the value being passed in. Your param name is correct. But you are passing in the index value of just `i`, but the C# `IDS` variable is a collection of ints, so you need to use the index variable `i` to get the appropriate item out of the `IDS` collection (else you need a `foreach` loop). And regarding #5, I thought you might say that ;-), but I noticed that you had closed the SqlDataReader so I figured it would be consistent to also close the connection :). But yes, a minor point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the parameter value in the application code rather than within the query.  I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish by casting the column value as a StringBuilder.  Assuming that each StringBuilder item is to contain a single string retrieved from a varchar/nvarchar column, the example below will do that.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < IDS.Count; i++)
 {
        var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select item From TransactiontData where idT=@IDS", con2);

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@IDS", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = IDS[i] };

        var rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr2.Read())
        {
            Items.Add(new StringBuilder((string)rdr2["item"]));
        }
 }
```

Comment: there is problem with index of list " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: That error implies your code has not initialized the List<StringBuilder>.  I changed the code to add the item to the collection.

Comment: A combination/merge of this answer and the other from @marc_s would be best / work. For this answer: 1) you should move the `var cmd2` line above the loop as it doesn't change, 2) you should move `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@IDS", SqlDbType.Int)` outside of the loop, 3) set `param` inside of the loop, 4) most likely don't need a `while` around the `rdr2.Read()`, and 5) you do need to close the reader since you can't issue another `ExecuteReader` until the current one is closed (right?).